# sharepoint solution won't deploy

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, web-parts, solution

I'm trying to deploy a SharePoint 2010 solution to our production environment, after starting the deployment process the deployment status keeps saying "Deploying".

At first I thought that the Timer jobs cache was clogging up, but after cleaning the cache and resetting the jobs counter the deployment still won't finish. I also double checked if the SharePoint Timer and Administration were down, but this wasn't the case.

I also reviewed the ULS logs but they don't seem to be holding any serious errors or problems.

Does anyone have a suggestion that might come in handy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have a different servers on WHich you are deploying your wsp ?

If yes, then check the timezone of that server.

Have a look at this link [it may help you](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jojok/archive/2011/04/14/sharepoint-2010-wsp-deployment-stuck-on-deploying.aspx.)

ANother this you can try is :
Did you try the steps described above?
1) Run stsadm -o execadmsvcjobs  on your CA server.
2) Run stsadm -o execadmsvcjobs on all the farm members that have stsadm.
4)Restart the Timer Service on all farm members.
5)If still not resolved, then try deleting the timer job that is causing the problem.

Comment: I executed all the steps you described and it worked. My solution finally deployed to the production environment.